# Haskell MonadState implement put with modify

Tags: haskell, state-monad

I want to implement put with modify

```
    put :: s -> m ()
    modify :: (s -> s) m s
```

when i do

```
    put s = modify $ const((), s)
```

i get the error,
Expected type: m ()
Actual type: m ((), s)
I have tried something like this

```
    modify $ const((), s) >>= \x -> return (fst x)
```

to get the expected type m() 
but this solution does not work

could someone explain to me how you can implement put by using modify?
Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`modify` has type

```
modify :: (MonadState s m) => (s -> s) -> m ()
```

The first argument is a plain `s -> s` function which modifies the state. So, while you are on the right track by trying to use `const`, you don't have to put the state in a tuple:

```
put s = modify $ const s
```

---

Note that, while you can define `put` in terms of `modify`, that means you won't be able to give a general definition of `modify`; rather, you have to do it for each concrete monad which is an instance of `MonadState`. That explains why, in `Control.Monad.State`, `get` and `put` are class methods of `MonadState`: how you implement them depends on the specific state monad. `modify`, then, is defined in terms of `get` and `put`.

Comment: thank you for your response,

how should I implement modify with the use of put and get.
your put implementation seems not working with my modify implementation. 
my implementation of modify is modify f = do { x <- get; put (f x) }

Comment: Your implementation of `modify` is correct, but it is done in terms of `get` and `put`; so if you try to implement `put` with `modify` it becomes circular. Are you implementing the methods for a specific state monad, or are you trying to write general implementations?

Comment: @Neckronis I updated the answer to make the point clearer. Does it help?

Comment: I am trying to write a general implementation.
Your updated answer helps, so if i define put in terms of modify i won't be able to implement a general definition of modify with put and get? is that correct

Comment: Yes. In that case, you can't provide default implementations for the three methods. How you get and put the state depends on the concrete data type; so all you can do generally is either define `modify` in terms of `get` and `put`, as in `Control.Monad.State`, or define `put` in terms of `modify` (though the former approach is better, as `put` is simpler than `modify`).

Comment: Ok thank you, I understand the subject better now, thanks for your time and help. Gonna try to implement it.